Outdated PHP 7 version with Google App Engine
I received the attached message for App Engine that PHP 7.4. will no longer be supported by Google from July 2024. Can someone tell me if there is a way to extend this deadline and how? Are there alternative ways to continue using App Engine without having to upgrade PHP? Does anyone have any experience with what happens after the deadline?
Many thanks for your help.
message php7 google app engine

Contact Google ans ask them. Usually such priority support cost a lot of money.
